# Give child element class if second level parent doesn't exists

Tags: jquery

I have a set of images that sets a language on my site - When one flag is clicked and it gets active - it no longer has an `a` element wrapped around it, as per the example below. How can I give the `img` that doesn't have an `a` element parent a class of "active"?

```
<div class="langsel">
    <a href="/se/netset/etailer/web/P98.m4n?localeCode=5">
        <img src="/images/lang/sv_inact.png" title="Swedish" alt="Swedish">
    </a>
    <img src="/images/lang/da.png" title="Danish" alt="Danish">
    <a href="/se/netset/etailer/web/P98.m4n?localeCode=7">
        <img src="/images/lang/fi_inact.png" title="Finnish" alt="Finnish">
    </a>
    <a href="/se/netset/etailer/web/P98.m4n?localeCode=6">
        <img src="/images/lang/no_inact.png" title="Norwegian" alt="Norwegian">   
    </a>
    <a href="/se/netset/etailer/web/P98.m4n?localeCode=1">
        <img src="/images/lang/en_inact.png" title="English" alt="English"> 
    </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to remove link from an a tag then you can remove it like, $('img').closest('a').removeAttr('href')

Comment: Here is the sample code https://jsfiddle.net/Lo8rz458/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want to select the `img` directly under `.langsel` without an `a` in between:

```
$('.langsel > img').addClass('active');
```

Though in this case you probably don't need to use JavaScript and the `active` class at all, you could just use this selector in CSS.

Comment: Oh that was easy! thanks a lot! And yeah - i need it this way due to some other factors. Thanks again - very helpful.